# Deprecated reference to top-level constant 'Task'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named 'Task' in my project.

I upgraded from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1 and now I receive the following error. My code hasn't changed.

```
>> Task.new
WARNING: Deprecated reference to top-level constant 'Task' found at: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2470:in `rakefile_location'
    Use --classic-namespace on rake command
    or 'require "rake/classic_namespace"' in Rakefile
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
    from (irb):1:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in `new'
    from (irb):1
```

I'm scared I've called my model something that should have been reserved, what should I do for best practice? Refactor and change the name? Or something else?

**Update:** I tried it's suggestion of updating the Rakefile, but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it turns out 'Task' has been a reserved word for a long time. I used text mate's find and replace to do a refactor, and created migrations to update the database. It only took about an hour, and I feel it was worthwhile to avoid future problems.

Comment: Ahhhhh I just encountered the same problem, I'll have to rename my model. I'll be sure to check this list next time: http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords

Comment: We've been having a Task model in a number of apps without any problems so far. Suddenly I run into this problem with 1 app :( — I've shared my findings in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I dug a bit deeper and found this out:

When my specs auto-load the Task constant, Rake's `const_missing` ([source code](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/6e3c542a2a38caeda6254a0eb19f6cf8009792d1/lib/rake/ext/module.rb)) kicks in, issues that warning ([source code](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/6e3c542a2a38caeda6254a0eb19f6cf8009792d1/lib/rake/classic_namespace.rb)) and returns `Rake::Task`. Which makes my specs fail because I'm now testing *that* instead of my model.

I then get a lot of these:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `enqueue' for Rake::Task:Class
```

Well, of course it doesn't implement `enqueue` — that's not my model!

So, in short, Rake tells me not to use their top-level `Task` (even though I didn't mean to), and provides me with a different constant, effectively breaking the auto-loading in Rails!

There's only way around that — I had to manually `require 'task'` in the spec. Now it's all ponies and rainbows.

Dear Jim Weinrich, if you read this: Next time you declare something deprecated, please ensure that you only warn people about this when they actually **use** a deprecated API!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to get rid of rake's deprecation warning.  In your spec_helper, before any activity that would reference the model, do this:

```
# Rake defines a const_missing that, if you reference any of several
# top-level constants, issues a deprecation warning and then defines
# it.  Since Rake defines it, rail's own const_missing doesn't
# happen, and our own class doesn't get loaded.  The workaround is to
# remove rake's const_missing.

class Module
  def const_missing(*args)
    rake_original_const_missing(*args)
  end
end
```

We could have renamed our model, but that was more work than this.  This, however, might break with future versions of rake.  Choose your poison.